# Removing substring combinations in Python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have job description text data that is stored in a data frame. I cleaned/preprocessed my data a little bit, including lowercasing and removing whitespaces, URLs, punctuation, stopwords, and HTML tags.

Next, I want to remove particular combinations of substrings. I give you an example:

If the text reads "required certification license registration" I want to remove the substring combination "certification licence" so that the output reads: "required registration". However, I want to keep the substrings if they appear separately in the text like this: "required certification include" [...] "with a license in".

I want to remove these substrings if they show up in a different order: "required license certification registration". Is there a different solution than using `str.replace`?

How do I tackle this? Should I tokenize words first?

Comment: What did you mean by **substrings combinations**? is it a text words separated by spaces?

Comment: Wouldn't string.replace("certification license", "") do the job (notwithstanding the double space it leaves behind) ?

Comment: Thanks @Swifty. That was my first thought but I also want to remove these substrings if they show up in reverse order (license certification). I have several of these 'word combinations', so I was hoping for a different, cleaner, simpler strategy. But you are right, it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `combinations` in a `list`, then loop through it.
every combination can be `reversed` in the next. here is an example below:

NB: regular combinations have marked by ****, while reversed ones are marked by ++++

```
combinations =["certification license", "particular combinations"]
               
text='''I want to remove particular combinations of substrings.
if the text reads "required certification license registration"
should also remove if they in a different order:
"required license certification registration".
'''


for combination in combinations:
    words = combination.split()
    reverse_combination = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    text=text.replace(combination,'***********')
    text=text.replace(reverse_combination,'++++++++++++')
  
print(text)
```

**Output**:

```
I want to remove *********** of substrings.
if the text reads "required *********** registration"
should also remove if they in a different order:
"required ++++++++++++ registration".
```